# Помогите разобраться со строками в си

Tags: c, массивы, строки, char

Суть задачи в том, чтобы вывести строку длины k, содержащую степени десятки от 1 (не показатели!). У меня прога работает до 57 символов, а потом вместо цифр выводит какие-то левые символы, например: 
Введите длину строки: 60
1101001000100001000001000000100000001000000001000000000./,),

Как это исправить, чтобы выводились только цифры?
 Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 1000

void Long_to_String(int number, char string[]) //перевод из int в string
{
    int i = 0;

    while (number != 0)
    {
        string[i] = '0' + (number % 10);
        number = int(number/10);
        i++;
    }

    string[i] = '\0';
    _strrev(string);
}

void str() //генерация и вывод строки степеней 10-ки длины k
{
    int k, deg, i=0;
    char pows[N], nums[N];
    printf("Введите длину строки: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);

    while (strlen(pows) != k)// запись в строку степеней 10-ки
    {   
        deg = pow(10, i);
        Long_to_String(deg, nums);
        strcat_s(pows, nums);
        nums[0] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    pows[k] = '\0';
    puts(pows);
    _getch();
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    str();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите. Например, k=5, что надо вывести? Какие степени?

Comment: `number = int(number/10);` вместо краткого и  очевидного `number /= 10;`. Вряд ли автор языка мог даже представить столь разрушительный эффект от повсеместного преподавания его творения...

Comment: Если к=5, нужно вывести 11010

Comment: Axeless Gaming: "... вывести строку длиной k (значений), содержащую степени числа 10 (начиная от 0)". Речь идёт о результате возведения в степень или о показателях степени? Ведь 0 может быть показателем, но не результатом при ненулевом основании. Какой вид должен иметь вывод: 0 1 2 3 4 (показатели степени)  или  1 10 100 1000 10000 ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void Long_to_nums(long int n, char s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        s[i] = '0' + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    strrev(s);
}

int main()
{
    int k = 10;
    float x = 0.;
    long int deg = 0;
    char pows[80] = "", nums[20] = "";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    while (k < 0 || k > 9) {
        printf("\nВведите k (0..9): ");
        scanf("%d", &k);
        if(k < 0 || k > 9)
            printf("k - вне допустимого диапазона!\n");
    }
    printf("\nПоказатели степени:\n");
    k++;
    while (k > 0) {
        deg = lroundf(pow(10., x));
        printf("%d ", (int)x);
        Long_to_nums(deg, nums);
        strcat(pows, nums);
        strcat(pows, " ");
        x++;
        k--;
    }
    printf("\nЗначения функции:\n%s\n", pows);
    return 0;
}
```